# What is the MALLOC_REALLOC VM region on iOS

Tags: ios, memory-management, virtual-memory

After profiling my app using Instruments, I noticed that the `MALLOC_REALLOC VM` region ended up with nearly 2GB of `Persistent Bytes`.
However, I am using an iPod that does not have as much memory, so I imagine I would have been killed if I were actually using that much memory.

I cannot find any documentation on what the `MALLOC_REALLOC` region is for, and what it means.

Does anyone have some pointer to useful documentation regarding that ?

Thanks

PS: examples of documentation links that I reviewed and are not useful to answer this question

- [Advanced Memory Management](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html)
- [Tutorial for finding memory leaks on ios](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2696/instruments-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-debug-memory-leaks)
- [Finding and fixing memory leaks on ios](http://www.slideshare.net/OwenGoss/finding-and-fixing-memory-leaks-in-ios-apps-5251292)
- [Memory Usage Performance Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/ManagingMemory/ManagingMemory.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000160-SW1)

Comment: I cannot answer with any authority but I imagine that the MALLOC_REALLOC region is a block of memory the OS reserves to handle malloc() and realloc () requests.